# Cannot resolve symbol 'android' - While implementing Google Analytics in Android App with libgdx

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-analytics, libgdx

I am trying to follow [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/) and import the analytics tracker. I have spend hours, but still no luck.

[image]

I keep getting the following error:

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'android'
```

This is where I have put my `classpath` line in my Project `build.grade`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'de.richsource.gradle.plugins:gwt-gradle-plugin:0.6'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
        classpath 'org.robovm:robovm-gradle-plugin:1.9.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2' // <-- HERE
    }
}
```

I have added these lines to my Android Module Gradle:

```
android {
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' // <-- HERE
```

and:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.3.0' // <-- HERE
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help.

P.S.: It works in the Analytics sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the problem!

I needed to do a Clean build and Rebuild. That was all!

Answer (score 0):

Your close you need to apply the `android` plugin first then apply the `google-services` plugin.  Then configure your `android` model in the closure

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    // blah
}

dependencies {
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0"
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.3.0'
    // blah
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. However, it still does not find the imports.